# RESTful WCF Service Fails When Large JSON POSTed

Tags: json, wcf, http-status-code-404

I'm writing a web application that calls a WCF RESTful interface. One of my service methods takes a string of JSON as a parameter. Calls to that method work great as long as the JSON string is under a specific length. As soon as the string exceeds that length, the service returns a 404 error. I've been looking for an answer to this and tried a couple of different ideas to address this, but the error persists.

The client-side code is:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUri + parameters);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

The contract for the service method is:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "MethodName?stages={stages}&providerID={providerID}")]
    string MethodName(string stages, int providerId);
```

The **stages** parameter above is the one that receives the long string of JSON.

I also added the following to the web.config file of the service:

```
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basichttpbinding_esynchrony"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

If anyone can help with an answer or even a link to an article that explains how to solve this particular issue, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I noticed that you have created an Http-POST request to the service while you specify that the operation is GET, could it work well? In my opinion, the service contract may have another binding, such as Webhttpbinding, with which could publish the WCF service in Restful style. In that cases, the server would accept JSON data, otherwise only SOAP message based on XML is accepted and HTTP verb is always POST.
Moreover, we usually use the following configuration in case the request exceeds the length.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbev" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webbev">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.